# How to call another service (function) before executing the res.view() function call using sails JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, sails.js

I would like to call a separate function (e.g. a Service function) before sails render the page into html. Please kindly refer my controller code below...

```
var MYController = {
   index: function(req, res, next) {

      req.flash("error", "Testing hello world"); 
      MyCustomServices.myFunction( req, res );
      res.view();
   }
}
```

Just to add my service function, api/services/MyCustomServices.js

```
exports.myFunction = function( req, res ){
   Test.findOne({ code : "CODE" }, function(err, resp) {
        if ( resp ) {
            res.locals.TEST = resp;
        }
   });

   var msg = req.flash('error');
   res.locals.ERROR = msg.length>0 ? msg : "" ;

};
```

In this scenario, before executing the res.view there is another process to run when I called MyCustomServices.myFunction( req, res );

The problem is, everytime I have the res.view() function call, I need to add this line in all my controller's action.

I tried to add this MyCustomServices.myFunction( req, res ); in express.js, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. But I think, it should be in express, it is just I don't know what codes I need to add.

What is inside my MyCustomServices.myFunction( req, res ) are:

1. A query to sails to fetch some data from MongoDB
2. Parse the req.flash messages to be passed in the views for displaying.

Anyone got idea on this?

Comment: can you show the code in myFunction()

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call `res.view` after your `Service` has finished executing, you could remove `res.view` from the controller, and put it in the service itself:

```
var MYController = {
  index: function(req, res, next) {
    req.flash("error", "Testing hello world"); 
    MyCustomServices.myFunction( req, res );
    //res.view();
  }
}
```

---

```
exports.myFunction = function( req, res ){
   Test.findOne({ code : "CODE" }, function(err, resp) {
        if ( resp ) {
            res.locals.TEST = resp;
            res.view(); //TADA
        }else {
            /* Handle Error */
        }
   });

   var msg = req.flash('error');
   res.locals.ERROR = msg.length>0 ? msg : "" ;

};
```

Comment: thanks... but thiss is not the approach I'm looking for... coz I have created already soo many controller actions, if I implement this, I need to call this function everywhere, which is difficult to manage... I was expecting for express.js instead. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

Two Options

Add a callback to your service

```
var MYController = {
   index: function(req, res, next) {

      req.flash("error", "Testing hello world"); 
      MyCustomServices.myFunction( req, res, function(){
          return  res.view();
      } );

   }
}

exports.myFunction = function( req, res, cb ){
   Test.findOne({ code : "CODE" }, function(err, resp) {
        if ( resp ) {
            res.locals.TEST = resp;
            return cb()
        }
   });

};
```

-- or (based on your comments) --

You could add a custom response handler to your app. Check out http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses

You can replace res.view() with res.ok() and then modify api/responses/ok.js with your service.

Or you can create your own response if you don't want to mess with ok.js

Comment: thanks but not this... Is there anyway somewhere in express.js, that this file will beexecuted right before res.view sails function called?